# Find $x+y+z$ when the values are solutions of the system $x={{y}^{2}}-2,y={{z}^{2}}-2,z={{x}^{2}}-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Find $x+y+z$ when the values are solutions of the system

$x={{y}^{2}}-2,y={{z}^{2}}-2,z={{x}^{2}}-2$

i tried several ways.first i add them together and i am to the point

$x+y+z={{(x+y+z)}^{2}}-2({{x}^{3}}+{{y}^{3}}+{{z}^{3}})+4(x+y+z)-6$

but im stuck there .then  i subtruct them but with no result.A help will be apreciated

Comment: $x+y+z$ is not unique - take $(x,y,z)=(2,2,2)$ and $(-1,-1,-1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting $z:=x^2-2$ and $y:=z^2-2$ the first equation becomes
$$
(x^3 + x^2 - 2x - 1)(x^3 - 3x + 1)(x + 1)(x - 2)=0.
$$
This yields all solutions. If $x=2$, then $(x,y,z)=(2,2,2)$ and $x+y+z=6$. If $x=-1$, then $(x,y,z)=(-1,-1,-1)$, and $x+y+z=-3$. Similarly, for the three real roots of $x^3-3x+1=0$, where we have $x+y+z=0$, and the three real roots of $x^3+x^2-2x-1=0$, where we have $x+y+z=-1$.

Comment: how to you get from  ${{x}^{3}}-3x+1=0$to x+y+z=0 .thank u very much !!!